# Create a AlertDialog in Android with custom xml view

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

[image]

How to create a dialog like this in Android?
My idea is to create a custom xml view and inflate it into the dialog. 
any other suggestions? 
and what is the "drag line" at the middle of the dialog called? I really need that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that "drag line" called progress bar or you can use there seekbar as well. And for your dialog see my answer.

Comment: The drag line you are talking about is called seek bar.

Comment: there is already an answer to your question here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/855843

Comment: @QuinnWei have you done it or not

Answer (score 19):

Try below code for your reference:

main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowCustomDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

dialog.xml: Make design whatever you want in dialog.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `Alert Dialog` and `Inflate Custom Layout` and set layout to your `Alert Dialog`.

Here is the link for some demo examples for reference

- http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/dialog/android-custom-dialog-example/
- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

and drag line is called as `Progress Bar/Seek Bar` in android. You can add this into your layout and handle it's progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the standard dialog for android if you are using the Holo theme. You just need to use the holo theme for your application and it should work.

Add this to your application tag in your manifest file
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"